# Accessibility issues in the react-native app

Tags: react-native, mobile, accessibility

I am working on the accessibility in the react-native and what issue i m facing is that when the app is run using keyboard, then all the touchable components are focused using tab navigation but they are not getting clicked when any keyboard key like enter is pressed

I tried some of the tips given in the "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html" but it is still not working.

Comment: Did you add key event handlers to those components?

Comment: No, I haven't added any key event handler and that's where i am facing problem, can you please share how to add key event handlers :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199745/how-do-i-listen-to-keyboard-input-in-react-native any good?