# React-Native: How to get zebra scanned barcode data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth, datawedge, zebra-scanners

I have zebra bluetooth scanner. I have connected that zebra scanner with bluetooth. Now my app should read whatever I scan any barcode. But How? Which library will read scanned barcode data? I have tried so many library but not working.
I have tried following packages but no luck:

1. react-native-scanner-zebra - emdk error while runing react-native run-android
2. @nextup/react-native-zebra-scanner - giving error on (on) event
3. react-native-datawedge-intents - Tried default example but not working.

Please help me with this. I have spent 2 days to fix this issue but not fixed yet. Plzz Plzz Help.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Do you have any documentation of the device? Some barcode scanners simply act as HID (e.g. keyboard)

Comment: I am using zebra scanner Modal - DS2278

Comment: Actually when I focused on textinput and then scan any barcode then barcode data appearing on textinput but I want it in backgound case. For ex: When I am on any screens and I scan any barcode then it's code will show in useeffect or any event.

Comment: Maybe you need to look for a way to capture keyboard input before that then. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199745/how-do-i-listen-to-keyboard-input-in-react-native

Comment: Yeah but it will only disable the keyboard.I also dont want to show textinput. I want to detect barcode scanner data without textinput.

Comment: Which Android device have you paired the DS2278 with?  FWIW I am the author of the react-native-datawedge-intents plugin

Comment: Realme 2 device I have paired with DS2278. I have used react-native-datawedge-intents plugin but for that I need datawedge application and that application we only get it in zebra device.

Comment: Same problem here, I can't make the three libraries you listed to work... Which one do you use now ?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, I have Zebra TC58 and already have an app. And want to integrate zebra sdk in my existing React native app, so that I can use scanner buttons inside my app and fetch the data from the barcode. Tried multiple libraries, but nothing is working. @MaxxP Can you please suggest, if you find any solution?